# How to fix native.newTextField orientation on rotation

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Our app only support `portrait` and we are manually rotating some objects, but we are stock with this `native.newTextField`

```
-- setupTextField
function setupTextField()

    local txNameBG = display.newImageRect( "images/login/login-input-bg.png", 225, 30 )
    txNameBG.x = _gameCenter.x
    txNameBG.y = _gameCenter.y
    sceneGroup:insert(txNameBG)
    _events.fixRotate(txNameBG)

    if (txName == nil) then
        txName = native.newTextField( _gameCenter.x, _gameCenter.y, 225, 30 )
        txName.hasBackground = false
        txName.inputType = "default"
        txName.placeholder = "INSERT NAME"
        txName.align = "center"
        txName.font = native.newFont( native.systemFont, 15 )
        txName:setTextColor( 163, 25, 12 )
        txName:addEventListener( "userInput", _events.textListener )
        sceneGroup:insert(txName)
        -- _events.fixRotate(txName)

    end 

end
```

---

Here is the function the we are using for rotating objects (only those native.*) are not responding.

```
eventClass.fixRotate = function ( obj )

    obj:rotate(90)
    obj.isFixedRotation = true
    -- obj.angularVelocity = 0

end
```

---

> This is the correct layout, but the text inside the `native.newTextField` was cut,

[image]

> This is what happen after rotating(`landscapeRight`)

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Cant you swap width and height as well on rotation?

Comment: Nope, I don't think i need to swap the width with height.. i was just rotating the object.. The other objects reacted perfectly, and by the why i only support `portrait` orientation

Comment: Can I ask you to file a bug report on this?  Please make up a small app that demonstrates the problem. The app must include a main.lua, config.lua and build.settings file and any assets needed to build and run the app. Put that in a .zip file and visit: https://developer.coronalabs.com/content/bug-submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I found a solution:

```
settings = 
{
    ...

    orientation =
    {
        // I changed
        // supported = { "portrait" }, to
        //
        supported = { "portrait", "landscapeRight", "landscapeLeft", "portraitUpsideDown"}
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, I found out that the text that was cut only occurs in `Corona Simulator`, but in real device (iP6plus in my case) it is looking pretty well. So as my personal advice, always test your app on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your build.setting

```
settings = {
    orientation =
    {
        default = "landscapeRight",
        content = "landscapeRight",
        supported = { "landscapeRight", "portrait" },
    },
}
```

Comment: Okay, i'll try this tomorrow, but one thing, our app only support 'portrait' orientation making it 'landscapeRight' will make it landscaped by default..

Comment: Shouldnt for portrait everything be right in the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how hardened the native.newTextField() is to being rotated manually. I've asked in the comments above to get a bug report submitted on this. I know for certain that textFields rotate properly when you have said you want to support both Portrait and Landscape orientations in your build.settings file.

I'm unsure why you want to do this by hand instead of using an onOrientation event to re-layout the page instead of hand rotating all your objects.

Rob

Comment: Thank you. 

Actually I ended up using `Runtime:addEventListener( "resize", onResize )` and relayout/rescale the objects.
Unfortunately I can't report just now; we're kinda late in schedule... But i'll surely submit soon...